# Weird error in FF addon sdk 1.17 when running

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

when i run my add-on (developed with the sdk 1.17) i get this weird error:

```
###!!! [Child][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: Route error: message sent to unknown
actor ID
```

otherwise my add-on works as it should. I updated to FF 33.0.2 and moved from SDK 1.16 to SDK 1.17 and that is when the error started to happen.

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this is related to the SDK, I suspect this is a Firefox warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a Firefox error, and not related to your add-on or the add-on sdk.

You can ignore it.